# How is google mock getting its object file?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I have a project that I am trying to use google mock with. I downloaded google mock 1.7 and complied it using Visual Studio Express 2013, and then added the gmock.lib and gmock_main.lib files to my lib directory. I also added the include folder to my include folder so that my project can import it.

Now whenever I try to build my project it gives me the linker error:

```
    error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match 
    value '1800'
```

It says it is in the file: `gmock.lib(gmock-all.obj)`. I complied google mock using a 2013 compiler so i'm not sure why it would give me this error. The only reason I can think of it giving this error still is that it is using some other `gmock-all.obj` file, but I don't know where it would be getting that file from.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: So it turns out the problem was that google mock's sln file was read only, so building it was not actually updating the compiler version. Simply make the sln file not read-only fixed my problem!

Comment: It's not necessarily the google mock library, but one of the binaries you're trying to link has been built with an older version of the compiler.

Comment: right but I compiled everything using Visual Studio 2013 and updated anything that was in 2010. Is there anything else I can do to fix this?

Comment: Since you mentioned it, you could try using the `/verbose` link option to make sure that you are linking with the correct gmock.lib.